# export table data into excel in meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

In my application starting URL `localhost:3000` takes me login page and after I login, it takes to `/afterlogin` for now every thing working fine, once I remove `/afterlogin` and enter it will take to login page again how to block that url after login and stay in home page in meteor?

Comment: What does this have to do with Excel?

Comment: Sorry that is my previews question i forgot to delete that tag. I am sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use / as the URL for user login, the more "Meteor.js" thing to do is use conditional logic in the main template for your site's landing page. The Meteor documentation for [Accounts](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/accounts) explains that applications should:

> Use `{{#if currentUser}}` to check whether the user is logged in.

Check out the [login example application](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/examples/other/login-demo/login-demo.html) to see how `{{#if currentUser}}` is applied in practice. I've copied the template below for convenience:

```
<template name="main">
  {{#if loggingIn}}
    <div class="loading">Loading...</div>
  {{else}}
    {{#if currentUser}}
      <div class="msgDiv">
        Signed in as: {{currentUser.services.google.email}}
      </div>
      <a href="#" id="logout">Sign out</a>
    {{else}}
      <a href="#" id="login">Sign In With Google</a>
    {{/if}}
  {{/if}}
  <div class="msgDiv">
    Client can see {{numGizmos}} gizmos.
  </div>
</template>
```

In the "main" template, you can see that the application uses Spacebars to check for the following conditions:

- if `loggingIn` is true (the user is logging in), display a loading screen
- if `loggingIn` is `false` AND `currentUser` is `true` (the user has already logged in), display a screen with the signed in user's information
- if `loggingIn` is `false` AND `currentUser` is `false` (the user hasn't signed in yet), display a prompt to sign in

Note: in this example application, they demonstrate login with the `accounts-google` authentication package, but you can use the same pattern for the basic `accounts-password` based login. Other authentication packages include `accounts-facebook`, `accounts-github`, `accounts-twitter`, and community packages.

If you are using `iron:router` in your application, then you can also secure the application URLs with logic like the following (taken from the docs):

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  if (! Meteor.userId()) {
    this.render('login');
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
});
```

Comment: Because I don't have enough reputation, I couldn't post a link to the `iron:router` docs. Here it is: https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router

Answer (score 0):

**step 1**  download  " alasql , XLSX ,  moment " packages form npm // meteor npm install alasql

**step 2**  import the alasql , XLSX and moment into file form where we have to create excel

```
            import alasql from 'alasql';
            import XLSX from 'xlsx';
            import moment from "moment";

            alasql.utils.isBrowserify = false;
            alasql.utils.global.XLSX = XLSX;
```

**step 3**  in the same file get data from server via call the method

```
          Meteor.call('getAllUserData', function ( err,userData ) { //get data form server call
        
            if ( !_.isEmpty( userData ) )
            {
                var opts = [
                    {sheetid:'User List',header:true}
                ];
                alasql('SELECT INTO XLSX("User-List-'+moment(new Date()).format('DD-MM-YYYY')+'.xlsx",?) FROM ?',
                    [opts,[
                        userData
                    ]]);
            }
        })
```